# How to pack a null char?

Tags: php, null, char, pack

I need make communication with socket's TCP/IP and pack a message, but I have problems with packing a null char.

**In documentation I have this:**

> The PMS must add NULL char at end of all char variables. Therefore, the char [20] declarations above (or equivalent Delphi declaration of [0..19] of char ) actually mean 19 usable characters plus 1 space for a NULL.

**This is my php code:**

```
$message = pack('N', 1431655765)                      //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
    . pack('N', 2863311530)                           //HEADER - uint32 ui32Synch1
    . pack('v', 1)                                    //HEADER - uint16 ui16Version
    . pack('V', 1)                                    //HEADER - uint32 ui32Cmd;
    . pack('V', 44)                                   //HEADER - uint32 ui32BodySize
    . pack('a20', "44436412")                         //BODY - char szLisence[20]
    . pack('a20', "Test_Program")                     //BODY - char szApplName[20]
    . pack('I', 0);                                   //BODY - int  nRet

    echo "<br/> Message - packed = " . $message . "<br/> strlen " . strlen($message);

    echo "<br/> Hex dump PHP = " . bin2hex($message);
```

**Output:**

Message - packed = UUUUªªªª,44436412Test_Program

strlen 62

Hex dump PHP = 55555555aaaaaaaa0100010000002c0000003434343336343132000000000000000000000000546573745f50726f6772616d000000000000000000000000

**C++:**

I'm rewriting a c++ application to PHP, and i have a hexdump of message i need to send to server in c++
**hexdump c++:**
55555555aaaaaaaa0100010000002c000000343434333634313200cdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd546573745f50726f6772616d00cdcdcdcdcdcdcd00000000

**Comparare hexdumps until  pack('V', 44):**

- PHP: 5555555aaaaaaaa0100010000002c000000
- C++: *55555555aaaaaaaa0100010000002c000000

**Comparare hexdumps until pack('a20', "44436412"):**

- PHP: 55555555aaaaaaaa0100010000002c000000343434333634313200000000000000000000000
- C++: 55555555aaaaaaaa0100010000002c000000343434333634313200cdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd

Like we can see the pack null char I'm adding like asked in the documentation, in php is different from in c++.

What I need to do to give the same pack null char?

Comment: Try `pack('a20', "Test_Program".chr(0))`instead of `pack('a20', "Test_Program").pack('I', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

After test a recently version of same c++ app i check in wireshark the message sent to server don't have the "cdcdcdcd..." when null char, already have "00000000" like PHP as, so the only thing i need to do is pack like this way:

```
pack('a20', "44436412");
```

Answer (score 0):

In php to pack a null char, just pack the null with "C"  is OK. Here is the code,

```
<?php
    $value = pack("C", null);
    echo $value;
    echo ord($value);
?>
```

You can run a online php run environment, and get the answer like this img,

[image]